# Cups Delay, DBus and Colord

Tags: services, dbus

I've had a problem with CUPs; printing has been delayed 20-30 seconds. I tracked it down to a dbus problem, which was caused by colord not starting properly when cups is started. If I start colord manually, printing works without the delay. But it consistently fails with a seemingly incorrect message

```
# systemctl status colord.service
● colord.service - Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/colord.service; static; vendor     preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources)

Apr 11 06:08:37 sysA systemd[1]: colord.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory
Apr 11 06:08:37 sysA systemd[1]: Failed to start Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
Apr 11 06:08:37 sysA systemd[1]: colord.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 11 06:08:37 sysA systemd[1]: colord.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

The error messages aren't very good; the start task exists, so it must be looking for some other file. How can I debug this?